# Narrow discriminated union by function parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a store which keys a few different types by their IDs

```js
interface Dog { type: "dog"; woofs: string; }
interface Cat { type: "cat"; meows: string; }
type Pet = Dog | Cat;
type AnimalState = Record<string, Pet>
```

And I would like a function that returns a pet specific type, by it's key/ID.

```js
function getSpecificAnimal(state: AnimalState, key: string, type: Pet["type"]) {
  const pet = state[key];

  if (pet.type === type) {
    return pet;
  }

  throw new Error("pet was wrong type");
}

const aDog = getSpecificAnimal(state, "a", "dog"); // should return type Dog, or throw an exception
```

But I cannot figure out how to get Typescript to narrow down the return of the `getSpecificAnimal` function.

I tried using generics and a type map to relate all the arguments, but Typescript still was not satisfied

```js
type PetTypeMap = {
  dog: Dog,
  cat: Cat,
}
function getAnimalOfType<T extends Pet, K extends T["type"]>(animals: AnimalState, id: string, type: K): PetTypeMap[K] {
  const pet = animals[id];
  //    ^?

  if (pet.type === type) {
    return pet;
  }

  throw new Error("wrong pet type");
}
```

I've [tried a bunch of other ways](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QVgW0BMUagBM8SJyC1OJ1e6qkD1SUMxtSAGkzwqL%20CiQajaaLXHrcgr-aECOs6eiuoYqStMgj4%20sgp4AGTyJBz78DWjR5FG1hUpaJQJkmLZtrsrLZj2DT5oWJZlhWlbeqhrb1o287WPhrbtg0xFdqurJ9gOQ4juO-ZQFOM5-NgC5GsuIirochHSbBwIQGwrxgJA6hEGA4JwNiNxQE8mkDEquwxKp-bqGCCmOgWIIQFciANhcVzMDpEBUCIG58v8ICaf2jAyieL7aiq1hPv5b6wZ%20igmua0bkESEGKOQ0ExcgCE4EhKF1F2ZFFtYpYElR7rVhlrYNPRUBNtYNLdmuXHAt5g7DmOE6CdOs7YOJK7ZLJwLKUQHD7JgwAgv04zFkZuymQg-ZsKwYC7BqQSTcAam7GCbD9ApuwACwAGwABwAJz7QAxKt61GZo4AQvtADsACsu0AAybYe%2023a5nybvynkTj51jHqe55KoFYDBYDOofoaEXftFsFxTMUGpCoAQBOMiBPOQZogrwSUpWl1Y2OkyAougTqFZVWUUXlFYFbRtZIyjaPZWAEkcSR0J1bxjUCUJrWLizUnCEc3VgL1pD7FwaPoGisB9Iwo3oOouxwLst1PYdADMACM234uYAByXnaL5sXIHrhN2ADr5A4h8Wm8YyBZrByDkEO0vvbyW6Dobv1gOrflg8DoNW%20D4UkJFTMxXDSiJab3vG0%20hNFY0FM5ZR1NVrTdbWAx0aVZxva1TxDX8ZOLUiXzHVriI6FyEUBAylSOAoXAwMprkkZyHSbx2Due4HooP5WmwqQUHACyUHSS4pqx7HVx3yB0uMVLfd5Mo-vXQUT7QLMz52Igr0bf3r6qW%20YOPZpyvjhOX9PhHFffD%20trPwg1wvWD3HYB8%20%20rx%20b%200Z87zvmxLMQA) and just cannot get this to work. Is this type of narrowing not possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to implement `getAnimalOfType()` with compiler-verified type safety as of TypeScript 4.7.  In order for the return type of depend on its inputs, you'd either need to make it an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) one.  Callers will be happy either way, but the compiler can't help you much inside the implementation.

---

Overloads are easy enough to write and call:

```
function getSpecificAnimal(state: AnimalState, key: string, type: "dog"): Dog;
function getSpecificAnimal(state: AnimalState, key: string, type: "cat"): Cat;
function getSpecificAnimal(state: AnimalState, key: string, type: Pet["type"]) {
    const pet = state[key];

    if (pet.type === type) {
        return pet; // no error
    }

    throw new Error("pet was wrong type");
}

const state = {
    a: { type: "dog", woofs: "a lot" },
    b: { type: "cat", meows: "incessantly" }
} as const;
const aDog = getSpecificAnimal(state, "a", "dog");
// const aDog: Dog
console.log(aDog.woofs.toUpperCase()) // A LOT
```

but their implementations are loosely checked (see [microsoft/TypeScript#10765](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10765)).  So even though the compiler won't complain, you need to take care that you've implemented it correctly:

```
if (pet.type !== type) { // <-- wrong check
    return pet; // <-- still no error
}
```

---

The generic version would have a call signature like

```
declare function getSpecificAnimal<K extends Pet['type']>(
    state: AnimalState, key: string, type: K
): Extract<Pet, { type: K }>;
```

using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) in its return type to say that you want to get just the member of the `Pet` union whose `type` property is the same as that of the `type` parameter.  It is also easy for callers:

```
const state = {
    a: { type: "dog", woofs: "a lot" },
    b: { type: "cat", meows: "incessantly" }
} as const;
const aDog = getSpecificAnimal(state, "a", "dog");
// const aDog: Dog
console.log(aDog.woofs.toUpperCase()) // A LOT
```

But implementation will give you the opposite problem from overloads; you'll get compiler warnings even if you write it correctly.  Generics and [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) don't often play nicely together:

```
function getSpecificAnimal<K extends Pet['type']>(
    state: AnimalState, key: string, type: K
): Extract<Pet, { type: K }> {
    const pet = state[key];

    if (pet.type === type) {
        return pet; // error,
        // Type 'Pet' is not assignable to type 
        // 'Extract<Dog, { type: K; }> | Extract<Cat, { type: K; }>'
    }

    throw new Error("pet was wrong type");
}
```

There are a lot of open issues about it in GitHub.  For the specific flavor of generic narrowing you'd need, there's [microsoft/TypeScript#46899](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46899).  It's listed as "Awaiting More Feedback", meaning they want to hear compelling use cases from the community before considering implementing it.  You might want to go there and contribute, but I don't know that anything would ever come of it.

For now the easiest way to proceed is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which is the general-purpose recourse for situations where you know more about the type of a value than the compiler does:

```
function getSpecificAnimal<K extends Pet['type']>(state: AnimalState, key: string, type: K) {
    const pet = state[key];

    if (pet.type === type) {
        return pet as Extract<Pet, { type: K }>; // <-- assert here
    }

    throw new Error("pet was wrong type");
}
```

But this is back to the same issue as with the overload implementation; you have to take care to implement correctly, because you won't get an error if you do it wrong:

```
if (pet.type !== type) { // <-- wrong check
    return pet as Extract<Pet, { type: K }>; // <-- still no error
}
```

---

So those are the options.  You can overload, or you can use a generic with a conditional return type.  Callers are mostly happy, but as implementer you need to take care because the compiler can't do much to help.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeywCeADhAFzIBEAJlhQNzIDu66MAzuW2FKJgwL4BYAFChIsRCgDCcMLnzEylBLPrIAthHSMOyLjxB9kQ4YRLIAChDkBeNFmQAfZDLB0RZlAEEQwdXAAbAGUwWRQ7ACUIBHQoKgAefV4AGktrAD4RERA4TTYiSWQAeQA3aAD0OCpcLOFkeuQYAFcQBDBgdBBkTGsgkgRgGGAEHz9AgAouMPJR-2DQyFSAawgCTm4UhRJyaloASnIMPhEGxpa2jq6esD7oweHZianIGd85kLDl1fWDTFTPHYqMAUA4uWTuOoNZqtdqdbq9fr3EZvJ4LJSPeafZArNZ6DaGf6KchWMAAbQongoAF09jVIad6jEQFxkCRbHiwqScVSIScGfVBshxmyAHSeZA2SVbCC0nB8-mnKDWJpQLpshgAeg1yBA6GQ0CgsXlDJMxtOYAAFobGDqIDaAKJQQ1QcYUNlMOBsJiGwzSkEQ06m+nIJks57hOkK5Bwch4AGUGiYCipZisXQUODICrA4zJM0NABGselgNUqU02nToCQbDYcHAAQIFGMxv40a9obcxs70aOEvhN0RQ2RYwCkzRqQzyYT+wDDS1Ic6LLgR0OWG7S-QAQgIoqmHGK6wItT7DF6AAqkQSFAZGwIOM9rSF15kAAZIoAFVqxuhFzh11uAZhwxABZYAphWcdpmQDEPkWbFvjxX5CW2Gck1BI453qX9YSuBE7mAlEAjAiD73DV5RzgiAvlxJICRLZRVFBVwsLOGFLgHQCkVA8DQkg8iYKIqiaJ+TZ4xJclKRpSMFR7d07HDLlVh5Woo0FYVrDFRRkAAQilTxZWQBd4gAWhM71OmwBALWiJZ835JUwBVNVrE1bVTPMrhgACAIdT1A0jWDQNVIVS1rVtB0nViV13UYT0LN9Sk9lYoMRCDHI8gKJBkAAcQgEBoGGOkf3OXDOKHB4iMdKB4gAaX1AAPSAQCoL0JIAck8dqqXScZ7I5F5BMoicENo-E-gY2rjVBe0mqgRAwHiElUjjIlkHq-h0hk-k5OsftFO5XkgoadTRXFSU7AM7ao2QRznNZVyjO1AKoDzY7+QXD9tPakl2uQcC-LkT02GATAcgLbd8D1cV+tOBd2tm7gFviI4VsmgQtucRH5raeJXDR+Naox9r+qDKMwu0CLkGq6K3T2uKvUYH1sCSlKQuw0qOIAiqRzmOrGua1q0jJTrFG63qBNgkacVE+jCdlfrdvZA7lKOtSYCFM7tIu6UFfehk7tVB6ga9bHkeW+RCeMdI3OQDz2zvKA5BspVSfZhkKZtArIudGL6fipnLL9ZLW3d04cK5-CgMq0cSL4iB+YgJr8qFjqup6qDBqlrEZaQsS1tqvWoyV-a0SUggVOEfrTs08U9MuxRDOMsyEqsmyEDs-XFWVI33Xis3cYt1bUI2m2nrtluvJ8vz9SiqA3ar-XPapmmXTpuQGdb4O2cX04e3Dfs5X1mNLbW3YkxTFh2B2TNs2bfg3qjItT9QiggWnCsdB2asIFreswEbPfVs7ZFzMi7MGHsh5sB2G5gRGOcxM7UUoHAac59-TGgXJA1c9hMAbmZFuHce4DxHGPFfNgZ5LzXlvPeR848Xzvi-IvNKQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and github issues for pointers. When I couldn't figure out what narrowed type intellisense should give me in the implementation, I figured this wasn't possible. Thanks also for teaching me about Extract!